# How to connect payara and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, payara

I want to connect payara server with MySQL server.

What I did?

I downloaded connector/J for MySQL.

I placed it in C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext

I started payara server.

I created Connection Pool on localhost:4848.

I tried to ping but I had errors each time.

Details:

- Payara version: 5.182
- Connector: I tried    mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar and after that 
  mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar because I have read that there is
  some problem with the newest version.
- I tried to place both of    connectors in different places:
  C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext, 
  C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib,
  C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\payara5\glassfish\lib.
- I also tried to    remove sun folder from grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar.
- Connection Pool:    ResourceType I tried DataSource, XADataSource,
  Connection Pool    DataSource.
- DataSource Classname I tried to change it from
  com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource to
  com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataSource to follow someones advice.
- Properties:    password, user/username (the same I use in MySQL
  Workbench),    serverName: localhost, databaseName (the same I
  created in MySQL    Workbench), portNumber: 3306 (I haven't changed),
  url:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/name_db.

Errors that occured:

- Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for :
  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.(Lsun/security/ssl/ProtocolVersion;Lsun/security/ssl/CipherSuite;Ljava/util/Collection;Lsun/security/ssl/SessionId;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
- Communication Link Failure

After trying to ping each time error occured. Each time I changed something I restarted server. I also downloaded payara again and tried. I also checked and MySQL server is running. What I did wrong or what else can I try?

Comment: I don't know where you got "someones advice" from. Did you go through these links? They contain some information that might help you: https://blog.payara.fish/using-mysql-with-payara and https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/2747

Comment: From this website blog.payara.fish/using-mysql-with-payara in fact. But I missed "cj" in description of the problem(I just also tried without it). Thank you, but I did it few times with this instructions. I also tried advices from comments.

Comment: Can you share your domain.xml after configuring the data source? Please make sure you replace user names and passwords before.

Comment: How are you initiating Payara startup? Payara Server comes with two domain directories (domain1 and production) containing configuration etc. The cause of issues in you case might be that you're starting the domain named 'production', while you put the database driver file under 'domain1'. I suggest that you either put the database driver file under the 'production' domain directory (lib subdir) or make sure to start the domain named 'domain1'.

Comment: <jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" name="ShipsBattlePool" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
      <property name="password" value="someDatabaseName"></property>
      <property name="databaseName" value="someDatabaseName"></property>
      <property name="serverName" value="localhost"></property>
      <property name="user" value="someUser"></property>
      <property name="portNumber" value="3306"></property>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/someDatabaseName"></property>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>

Comment: I am going to payara5>bin and then 'asadmin start-domain domain1'.

Comment: <property name="useSSL" value="false"></property>
      <property name="allowPublicKeyRetrieval" value="true"></property>
I added two more properties, but I believe this is a temporary solution? Anyway it is working now and ping succeded!

Answer (score 1):

Try this with asadmin

```
create-jdbc-connection-pool --ping --restype javax.sql.DataSource --datasourceclassname com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource --property user=root:password=password:DatabaseName=dbname:ServerName=127.0.0.1:port=3306:useSSL=false:zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL:useUnicode=true:serverTimezone=UTC:characterEncoding=UTF-8:useInformationSchema=true:nullCatalogMeansCurrent=true:nullNamePatternMatchesAll=false MySqlPool
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to configure MySql using the GUI, but I wasn't successful. I tried many ways (as described in other thread within stack overflow) to fix the issue, but was never successful using the GUI. But I tried creating the connection pool from the command prompt and was successful in the first attempt.

```
create-jdbc-connection-pool --ping --restype javax.sql.DataSource --datasourceclassname com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource --property user=root:password=password:DatabaseName=test:ServerName=127.0.0.1:port=3306:useSSL=false:zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL:useUnicode=true:serverTimezone=UTC:characterEncoding=UTF-8:useInformationSchema=true:nullCatalogMeansCurrent=true:nullNamePatternMatchesAll=false MySqlPool
```

I would suggest others facing problem while creating connection pool via GUI, to try from the command prompt using 'asadmin'

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
download mysql driver jar
through the following command add jar to payara
asadmin add-library /path/to/mysql-connector-java-bin.jar
delete before pool,and restart payara
build new pool
this is work for me